# How to use ViewFlipper(or)ViewSwitcher and TextSwitcher in the same activity..?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-view

Im a begineer in android dev. Im able to implement textSwitcher and ViewSwitcher ,but individually in an activity. I want them to function in the same activity.

This code doesn't give me errors in the IDE but its "Force Closing" in the emulator.

The code after the imports and all..

```
ViewFlipper vS1,vS2,vS3;
Button onep,twop,lose,win,help,settings,start,pick1,pick2;
int condn,total,max=5,min=1,rem;
TextSwitcher minte,maxte,select1,select2,coinsrem;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Animations

    Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

//  Text Views ----
    minte.findViewById(R.id.min);
    maxte.findViewById(R.id.max);

   minte.setFactory(new TextSwitcherFactory());
   maxte.setFactory(new TextSwitcherFactory());

   minte.setText("Hello");

     // switching Views ----

    vS1 =(ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.vs1);
    vS2 =(ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.vs2);
    vS3 =(ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.vs3);

    vS1.setInAnimation(in);
    vS1.setOutAnimation(out);
    vS2.setInAnimation(in);
    vS2.setOutAnimation(out);
    vS3.setInAnimation(in);
    vS3.setOutAnimation(out);

 // create RangeSeekBar as Integer range between 20 and 75
    RangeSeekBar<Integer> seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(20, 75, getBaseContext());
    seekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    // add RangeSeekBar to pre-defined layout
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.rangeseek);
    layout.addView(seekBar);

    //----buttons-------------------------

    win = (Button)findViewById(R.id.win);
    lose = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loses);

    win.setOnClickListener(this);
    lose.setOnClickListener(this);

    //----buttons end----------------------
    //---Animating the views---



}







@Override
public void rangeSeekBarValuesChanged(Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}







public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {

    case R.id.win:
        condn = 1;
        vS2.showNext();

        break;
    case R.id.loses :
        condn =0;
        vS2.showNext();

        break;



    }
}

public class TextSwitcherFactory implements ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory{

    @Override
    public View makeView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView t = new TextView(LastActivity.this);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        t.setTextSize(36);
        t.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 204, 51));
        return t;       }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
minte.findViewById(R.id.min); 
maxte.findViewById(R.id.max);
```

doesn't make sense...

You should initialaze them like:

```
minte =(TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.min);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like you're attempting to initialize 3 separate ViewFlippers and switch between them.   This is not how to do this.   A ViewFlipper (or ViewSwitcher) is an extension of the FrameLayout class.  So, it will only show 1 child view at a time.

To fix  your code, define only a single ViewFlipper.   Under that, define the 3 views (i.e. RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc) that you want to switch between.

Also, it looks like you're trying to do some animation as well.  So,  you may ultimately want to use the ViewAnimator class instead, which is just the parent class of ViewFlipper.

Google for some tutorials.  There are some good ones out there.

I hope this helped!